# How to make the interactive area(move,scale,rotate) of Scatter widget cover the left and below of child widget in Kivy?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, drag, scatter

**1, My question**

When using Scatter widget to add some child widget(like label/image), how to make the interactive area(move/rotate/scale) of Scatter not just limited by the initial size of window？Because this will make the areas to the left and below the child widget(button k in my case) to be undraggable.

**2, Example**

[current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwTFw.png)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter

class Xapp(App):
    def build(self):
        ss=Scatter()

        k=Button(text='this is a k',font_size=30)
        k.size=(200,100)
        ss.add_widget(k)

        return ss

Xapp().run()
```

**3, What I want to achieve**

[interactive area to be wrap around or cover button k](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxRag.png)

Ideally, the interactive area of Scatter should be infinitely large, as if button k were a pattern on the Photoshop layer(like illustration-E). If that's not possible, is it possible to align the center of the button with the center of the interactive area of scatter? (like illustration-D)

Comment: Try using `ScatterLayout` instead of `Scatter` with `pos_hint`. You can even try `ScatterPlane`.

Comment: @ApuCoder, It seems like an ideal solution, Thanks a lot.